# type casting int to double java?

Tags: java

I'm practicing debugging and there is a question that i'm unsure on, it's asking what is wrong and what can I do to fix it I read the book chapter on it but not specific enough. pasted from the book:

int a = 26.4
        ^
When you compile, this is the message:

Test.Java:8: possible loss of precision 
int a = 26.4;

required: int 
found : double 
1 error

I have a decent understanding on why there is an error, because of how double has a higher precedence than int and how an int cant necessarily store a double value.

My question is, is there a way to type cast variable a into a double type? Or is the only way to fix this by changing a from int to double?

thanks

Comment: Even if you typecast it, it will still have the loss of precision. Only way I know of to fix would be to make `a` a double.

Comment: A variable's type is not only a _view_ (or similar) to the value that you can later widen with some sort of cast. It represents the memory space and its value representation inside that space. The primitive `int` type is a 32-bit type that stores integer values in two's complement form. After assigning the value to such a variable any further information (about decimals, e.g.) are lost.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only possibilities you have are:

- Type cast the `double` into an `int` if you want to store your number as an integer:

  ```
  int a = (int)26.4   // so a will be 26
  ```

  (you will obviously lose precision this way)
- Store the number as a `double` to keep the precision:

  ```
  double a = 26.4
  ```

Answer (score 9):

Casting will not help at anything, look at the code below:

```
//int a = 26.4; // gives compile error
int a = (int) 26.4; // gives 26
double b = a; // gives 26.0
double c = (double) a; // also gives 26.0
```

Comment: The first line of code doesn't give you anything except a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a decent understanding on why there is an error, because of how double has a higher precedence than int and how an int cant necessarily store a double value.

Although "precedence" isn't the correct terminology, you seem to understand at the problem at some basic level. When you cast a `double` to an `int`, you can lose information. In this case, `26.4` will be truncated to `26`.

> My question is, is there a way to type cast variable a into a double type?

A typecast changes the type of a **value** from one type to another. You cannot use typecasting to change the type of a **variable**. Once `a` is declared as an `int`, it is always an `int`. You cannot change that. However, the value stored in `a` can be cast to other types when it is used in expressions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to fix this, and which is right depends on the application.

The first to to keep the left-hand type as `int`, and cast the right-hand side to `int`:

```
int a = (int) 26.4;
```

This is right if rounding toward zero, and limiting values to the range `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is okay for your application.

Next, you might change the type of the left-hand side to `double`.

```
double a = 26.4;
```

This would be right if further operations using `a` can be performed with `double`. This won't work if you have to have an `int` value, for example, in order to pass to some API that requires `int`, or to specify the length or index of an array.

Or, you might need to explicitly control the rounding and range checking using the `Math` API. For example, to round to the *nearest* integer, and throw an exception if the value is too large for an `int`:

```
int a = Math.toIntExact(Math.round(26.4));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the follow code may help you.
In the below code, it is converting a double into an integer variable, although it is a little tedious process for such a simple thing.

`double a=26.4;
int b =(int)Math.round(a);`